# Handling events from remote webpage directly to the app using InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I would like to open an external webapp from my cordova app and handle webapp events directly on the native app. For instance, when a specific URL is loaded the app should handle it by calling a function. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is definitly possible to handle some events with the InAppBrowser. If you look [at the API docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#addEventListener) you'll see an `addEventListener` function that you can use. Currently it looks like the list of events you can listen for on the external page are still somewhat limited:

1. loadstart - event fired when the InAppBrowser starts to load a URL
2. loadstop - event fired when the InAppBrowser finished loading a URL
3. loaderror - event fired when the InAppBrowser encounters an error loading a URL
4. exit - event fired when the InAppBrowser window is closed

It looks like for your purposes you could just use the `loadStart` or `loadStop` events (not sure which would be best for your purpose, probably `loadStart()`.)

Here is some example code:

In the HTML page that you are using to open the inAppBrowser:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
     var ref = window.open('http://your.site.com/page', '_blank', 'location=yes');
     ref.addEventListener("loadstop", IABcallback);
}

function IABcallback(o){
    console.log("InApBrowser loaded: " +  o.url);
    if( o.url === "http://your.site.com/page2.html"){
        // Do whatever special stuff you want to do for page2 here
    }
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This does work, I was trying to make it work by working with the API, even if it limited. Though, I found out that my problem was a bit more complicated. This WILL NOT work if the webapp uses JQuery Mobile. So, I had to redirect to an external .hmtl webpage and it worked.

Comment: this will open a browser session outside the application. is it possible to achieve the same thing loading the new page into the app itself? for example using window.location="www.mysite.com" or another method