# Open link in native browser from InAppBrowser

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm building an app that uses the InAppBrowser quite a lot. At some point, the user is able to click an external link from within this window. I tried diffrent methods, but none seems to get a good working result.

The best solution so far is listening to the `loadstart` event ([As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275845/handling-events-from-remote-webpage-directly-to-the-app-using-inappbrowser)):

```
app.browser.addEventListener('loadstart', function (inAppBrowser) {
    if(inAppBrowser.url.match(/domain\.com/) === null) {
        var url = inAppBrowser.url;
        window.open(url, "_system");
    }
}
```

This opens the link in a new window, but also in the original InAppBrowser. Is it possible to cancel this event? Or is there a other approach i can try?

I already tried the following approaches:

- [Cross window communication](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser).
- Inserting a `history.back(-1)` via the [executeScript](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#executeScript) method.
- Call the `window.open(url, '_system');` from within the InAppBrowser.

This is for iOS specific.

**EDIT:**
I ended up by adding this code in `platforms/ios/APPNAME/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/CDVInAppBrowser.m`:

```
NSString *domainStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"domain.com"];
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", request.URL];
NSRange result = [urlStr rangeOfString:domainStr];

if(result.location == NSNotFound) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];

    return NO;
}
```

above this code:

```
return [self.navigationDelegate webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, InAppBrowser is for navigating through external links. Why don't you want the user to use InAppBrowser to navigate?

Comment: The InAppBrowser opens an external website, but that website has also external links. That links i want to open in the native browser as there not part of the website that comes with the app.

Comment: If the links aren't part of the website that comes with the app why do you show them? Anyways, I'm going to tell you some options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options:

- hide the external links injecting css to inappbrowser, if they don't appear, then they can't be clicked

add a loadstop listener and then hide the links

```
app.browser.addEventListener('loadstop', hideLinks);



function hideLinks(){
    app.browser.insertCSS({
                      code: "a { display: none; }"
                      }, function() {
                      console.log("Styles Altered");
                      });
}
```

- modify/subclass inappbrowser, changing the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method

change the `return [self.navigationDelegate webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];` to return `NO` if the `URL` isn't yours

Comment: Thanx, changing the return did fix my problem.

Comment: But be careful, when you update your cordova version it will overwrite the inappbrowser code again.